# GHC cannot deduce an instance exists despite being mentioned in a quantified constraint

Tags: haskell

I have the following program:

```
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# language PolyKinds #-}
{-# language QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# language RankNTypes #-}
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# language TypeApplications #-}
{-# language UndecidableInstances #-}

module Control.IO.GWeave where

import Generics.Kind


newtype HigherOrder e m a =
  HigherOrder ( e m a )


weaveFromTo
  :: forall m n e a code.
     ( GenericK e ( LoT2 n a )
     , GenericK e ( LoT2 m a )
     , GWeave ( RepK e ) m n ( LoT2 m a ) ( LoT2 n a )
     )
  => ( forall x. m x -> n x ) -> HigherOrder e m a -> HigherOrder e n a
weaveFromTo eta ( HigherOrder a ) =
    HigherOrder ( toK ( gweave @_ @m @n @( LoT2 m a ) @( LoT2 n a ) eta ( fromK a ) ) )

class GWeave f ( m :: * -> * ) ( n :: * -> * ) as bs where
  gweave :: ( forall x. m x -> n x ) -> f as -> f bs

class Effect e where
  weave :: ( forall x. m x -> n x ) -> e m a -> e n a

instance
  ( forall n a. GenericK e ( LoT2 n a )
  , forall m n a. GWeave ( RepK e ) m n ( LoT2 m a ) ( LoT2 n a )
  ) => Effect ( HigherOrder e ) where
  weave eta =
    weaveFromTo eta
```

In this, I have `class Effect e where weave = ...`. I want to use `DerivingVia` to provide instances of `Effect` for any data type that is an instance of `GenericK` (from the `kind-generics` library on Hackage). This is perfectly doable, and `weaveFromTo` is the bulk of the work. The last step is to simply say `instance Effect (HigherOrder e) where weave f = weaveFromTo f`. However, GHC seems to refuse to accept this, even if I add the necessary constraints onto the instance declaration for `Effect (HigherOrder e)`:

```
• Could not deduce (GWeave (RepK e) m n (LoT2 m a) (LoT2 n a))
  from the context: (forall (n :: * -> *) (a :: k).
                     GenericK e (LoT2 n a),
                     forall (m :: * -> *) (n :: * -> *) (a :: k).
                     GWeave (RepK e) m n (LoT2 m a) (LoT2 n a))
    bound by an instance declaration:
               forall k (e :: (* -> *) -> k -> *).
               (forall (n :: * -> *) (a :: k). GenericK e (LoT2 n a),
                forall (m :: * -> *) (n :: * -> *) (a :: k).
                GWeave (RepK e) m n (LoT2 m a) (LoT2 n a)) =>
               Effect (HigherOrder e)
```

I'm unable to work out why GHC is unhappy. Can anyone see the problem? The code above should work provided you have `kind-generics` installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use a `newtype`, just moving the type family application `RepK e` outside of the quantification makes it work (the change is in the line marked as `(!)`):

```haskell
instance
  ( forall n a. GenericK e ( LoT2 n a )
  , r ~ ( RepK e )  -- (!)
  , forall m n a. GWeave r m n ( LoT2 m a ) ( LoT2 n a )
  ) => Effect ( HigherOrder e ) where
  weave eta =
    weaveFromTo eta
```

This is because, by design, instances in Haskell cannot use type families. That is, you cannot write an instance that looks like:

```haskell
instance Eq (RepK e) where ...
```

Quantified constraints inherit that restriction, since they introduce sort of "local instances". You can find more information in the [GHC tracker](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/14860) and in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8vsnnb/quantified_constraints_type_families/).

As an extra piece of advice, everytime you use `RepK e` in `kind-generics`, always give it an explicit name outside of any quantification. Otherwise you end up with weird errors like the one you got.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution - I have to package up `RepK` into a newtype:

```
weaveFromTo
  :: forall m n e a code.
     ( GenericK e ( n :&&: a :&&: LoT0 )
     , GenericK e ( m :&&: a :&&: LoT0 )
     , GWeave ( WrappedRepK e ) m n ( LoT2 m a ) ( LoT2 n a )
     )
  => ( forall x. m x -> n x ) -> HigherOrder e m a -> HigherOrder e n a
weaveFromTo eta ( HigherOrder a ) =
    HigherOrder ( toK ( unWrapRepK ( gweave @_ @m @n @( LoT2 m a ) @( LoT2 n a ) eta ( WrapRepK @e ( fromK a ) ) ) ) )

class GWeave f ( m :: * -> * ) ( n :: * -> * ) as bs where
  gweave :: ( forall x. m x -> n x ) -> f as -> f bs

instance GWeave ( RepK e ) m n ( LoT2 m a ) ( LoT2 n a ) => GWeave ( WrappedRepK e ) m n ( LoT2 m a ) ( LoT2 n a ) where
  gweave eta ( WrapRepK a ) =
    WrapRepK ( gweave eta a )


instance
  ( forall n a. GenericK e ( LoT2 n a )
  , forall m n a. GWeave ( WrappedRepK e ) m n ( m :&&: a :&&: LoT0 ) ( n :&&: a :&&: LoT0 )
  ) => Effect ( HigherOrder e ) where
  weave eta =
    weaveFromTo eta

newtype WrappedRepK r a =
  WrapRepK { unWrapRepK :: RepK r a }
```

I think it's because `RepK` is a type family, so... something goes screwy? I'd love to know more about why this fix works.

Comment: Type families are not injective, e.g. it might happen that `F Int = F Bool = String`. So instance selection can become ambiguous: if you need `GWeave (Rep e1)...` and you know `forall ...(...=> GWeave (Rep e2) ...)`, you can deduce you want `Rep e2 = Rep e1`, but this is not enough to imply `e2=e1`. Newtypes are instead injective.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. It's something I'm aware of, but not the in the heat of the moment. I'll see if I can submit a bug report to get a better error. It would be very helpful if GHC said "BTW RepK isn't injective so I'm stuck"